How to debug docker build with yarn
I am having an issue with using node:18-alpine in my Dockerfile (even in the getting-started demo). When I run docker build -t 'getting-started' . I receive the following error:
 => [3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN yarn install --production                                                                                                                                                                                           0.4s
------
 > [4/4] RUN yarn install --production:
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     WORKDIR /app
   5 |     COPY . .
   6 | >>> RUN yarn install --production
   7 |     CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
   8 |     EXPOSE 3000
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn install --production" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139

But there is no information regarding what caused yarn install to fail other than exit code: 139. How would I view logs related to this error?
For reference here is the full Dockerfile and output:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000

Running docker build -t 'getting-started' . yields:
[+] Building 2.9s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                            docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 182B                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                                                                                                                               1.2s
 => [auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:dbbd5e059e8a07ff7ea6233b213b36aa516b4c53c645f1817a4dd18b83cbea56                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                                                                                                                                                       0.6s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:80338ff3fc4e989c1d5264a23223cec1c6014e812e584e825e78d1a98d893381                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring context: 11.98kB                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.3s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN yarn install --production                                                                                                                                                                                           0.4s
------
 > [4/4] RUN yarn install --production:
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |     WORKDIR /app
   5 |     COPY . .
   6 | >>> RUN yarn install --production
   7 |     CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
   8 |     EXPOSE 3000
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn install --production" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139

I've tried a number of suggested fixes, but at this point I'd really like to see some more detailed logs of what is causing the error.
